# Xcode 8: use of unresolved identifier error even though files share same Target Membership

Tags: swift, xcode

Code inside `AppDelete.swift` generates an `Use of unresolved identifier` error even though the function in question -- `Flurry.setAppVersion` -- belongs to a library (i.e., libFlurry_7.6.3.a) that shares the same Target Membership.

What else could cause this error?

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Flurry.setAppVersion(gAppVersion)
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you haven't yet created the bridging header like [the documentation outlines](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/ios/#swift-sdk-integration).

Comment: @Rob please post as an answer! Such a silly mistake, but you're too awesome; thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unable to resolve that `Flurry` reference. It would appear that you haven't yet created the bridging header like the documentation outlines: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/ios/#swift-sdk-integration